# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Tags: wp-config, fatal-error, errors

I have made wordpress pages on divi builder on m localhost and they were working fine without any problem but when i installed divi on my online website its giving me the error **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)**

I tried changing the **define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '40M' );** in both my wp-config and default-constants.php file  but its still giving the same error!

This error appears when ever I open my homepage. I searched online for man solutions but still cant find a solution :(

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` isn't going to help if a limit is set by your hosting. Contact your host and ask them to increase your memory limit.

Comment: I thought the problem was from my side, I contacted the hosting support and they fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Add the following at the top of wp-config.php:**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```

Although you should use `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` when you can, we see in /[wp-includes/default-constants.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-constants.php) that Wordpress doesn't do much more than use `ini_set` itself. Note: This is just one more thing to try, but you'll likely end up having to have your host fix this issue.